# query to find top 3 from a subquery

Tags: sql-server

I created a query

```
SELECT  Years 
        ,Months
        ,VulName
        ,Vulcount
        ,SUM(VulCount) OVER(PARTITION BY  VulId) AS  Totals 
FROM
( 
    SELECT  YEAR(outertblissues.OpenDt) AS Years 
            ,MONTH(outertblissues.OpenDt) AS Months
            ,outertblvulnerability.VulId
            ,outertblvulnerability.VulName
            ,COUNT(outertblvulnerability.VulId) Vulcount
    FROM    tbl_apptestdetails AS outertblapptestdetails 
            INNER JOIN tbl_applicationlist AS outertblapplicationlist 
                ON outertblapptestdetails.appid=outertblapplicationlist.appid 
            INNER JOIN tbl_bu AS outertblbu 
                ON outertblbu.buid=outertblapplicationlist.buid 
            INNER JOIN tbl_Issues AS outertblissues 
                ON outertblapptestdetails.testdetailid=outertblissues.testdetailid 
                   AND outertblissues.Status NOT IN('1','4')  
            INNER JOIN tbl_vulnerability AS outertblvulnerability 
                ON outertblissues.VulId=outertblvulnerability.VulId
    GROUP   BY YEAR(outertblissues.OpenDt)
               ,MONTH(outertblissues.OpenDt)
               ,outertblvulnerability.VulId
               ,outertblvulnerability.VulName
) a
ORDER BY Totals DESC
```

Which gives the output
[image]

I just want to pick all those records which lies in the largest top(3) Totals and one thing to keep in mind is if Totals of more than one VulName are same then the result should contain only distinct top 3 VulName , Totals is my last column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you, wrapping your first query inside a cte (removing the order by clause), then use another cte to establish the top three rows you're interested in which then filters your final select by the inner join;

```
WITH cte_Select AS
(
    SELECT  Years 
            ,Months
            ,VulName
            ,Vulcount
            ,SUM(VulCount) OVER(PARTITION BY  VulId) AS  Totals 
    FROM
    ( 
        SELECT  YEAR(outertblissues.OpenDt) AS Years 
                ,MONTH(outertblissues.OpenDt) AS Months
                ,outertblvulnerability.VulId
                ,outertblvulnerability.VulName
                ,COUNT(outertblvulnerability.VulId) Vulcount
        FROM    tbl_apptestdetails AS outertblapptestdetails 
                INNER JOIN tbl_applicationlist AS outertblapplicationlist 
                    ON outertblapptestdetails.appid=outertblapplicationlist.appid 
                INNER JOIN tbl_bu AS outertblbu 
                    ON outertblbu.buid=outertblapplicationlist.buid 
                INNER JOIN tbl_Issues AS outertblissues 
                    ON outertblapptestdetails.testdetailid=outertblissues.testdetailid 
                       AND outertblissues.Status NOT IN('1','4')  
                INNER JOIN tbl_vulnerability AS outertblvulnerability 
                    ON outertblissues.VulId=outertblvulnerability.VulId
        GROUP   BY YEAR(outertblissues.OpenDt)
                   ,MONTH(outertblissues.OpenDt)
                   ,outertblvulnerability.VulId
                   ,outertblvulnerability.VulName
    ) a            
)

, cte_Top3_Vulcount as
(

    SELECT TOP (3)
        Totals
    FROM cte_Select
    GROUP BY Totals
    ORDER BY Totals DESC
)

SELECT  s.Years 
        ,s.Months
        ,s.VulName
        ,s.Vulcount
        ,s.Totals 
FROM cte_Select s
INNER JOIN cte_Top3_Vulcount t3
    on t3.[Totals] = s.[Totals]
```

Actually, an hour ago the requirement was clarified to be;

> Top three unique `Vulname` ordered by `Totals`

On that basis, replace the content of `cte_Top3_Vulcount` with the following;

```
    SELECT TOP (3)
        VulName
    FROM cte_Select
    GROUP BY VulName
    ORDER BY max(Totals) DESC
```

The entire query would become;

```
WITH cte_Select AS
(
    SELECT  Years 
            ,Months
            ,VulName
            ,Vulcount
            ,SUM(VulCount) OVER(PARTITION BY  VulId) AS  Totals 
    FROM
    ( 
        SELECT  YEAR(outertblissues.OpenDt) AS Years 
                ,MONTH(outertblissues.OpenDt) AS Months
                ,outertblvulnerability.VulId
                ,outertblvulnerability.VulName
                ,COUNT(outertblvulnerability.VulId) Vulcount
        FROM    tbl_apptestdetails AS outertblapptestdetails 
                INNER JOIN tbl_applicationlist AS outertblapplicationlist 
                    ON outertblapptestdetails.appid=outertblapplicationlist.appid 
                INNER JOIN tbl_bu AS outertblbu 
                    ON outertblbu.buid=outertblapplicationlist.buid 
                INNER JOIN tbl_Issues AS outertblissues 
                    ON outertblapptestdetails.testdetailid=outertblissues.testdetailid 
                       AND outertblissues.Status NOT IN('1','4')  
                INNER JOIN tbl_vulnerability AS outertblvulnerability 
                    ON outertblissues.VulId=outertblvulnerability.VulId
        GROUP   BY YEAR(outertblissues.OpenDt)
                   ,MONTH(outertblissues.OpenDt)
                   ,outertblvulnerability.VulId
                   ,outertblvulnerability.VulName
    ) a            
)

, cte_Top3_VulName as
(
    SELECT TOP (3)
        VulName
    FROM cte_Select
    GROUP BY VulName
    ORDER BY max(Totals) DESC
)

SELECT  s.Years 
        ,s.Months
        ,s.VulName
        ,s.Vulcount
        ,s.Totals 
FROM cte_Select s
INNER JOIN cte_Top3_VulName t3
    on t3.VulName = s.VulName
```

Comment: Please Remove  ' , ' after " MONTH(outertblissues.OpenDt) AS Months " and please put ' , ' before COUNT(outertblvulnerability.VulId) Vulcount. just do these edits and this is the answer, Big Thanks to you :)

Comment: @Ashu corrected as you have noted. Might be good to correct your original Sql in your question too ;-) Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

here is one option:

```
WITH    CTE
          AS (
              SELECT
                c.Years
              , c.Months
              , c.VulName
              , c.Vulcount
              , SUM(c.Vulcount) OVER (PARTITION BY VulId) AS Totals
              FROM
                (
                 SELECT
                    YEAR(i.OpenDt) AS Years
                  , MONTH(i.OpenDt) AS Months
                  , v.VulId
                  , v.VulName
                  , COUNT(v.VulId) Vulcount
                 FROM
                    tbl_apptestdetails AS atd
                 INNER JOIN tbl_applicationlist AS al
                    ON atd.appid = al.appid
                 INNER JOIN tbl_bu AS bu
                    ON bu.buid = al.buid
                 INNER JOIN tbl_Issues AS i
                    ON atd.testdetailid = i.testdetailid
                       AND i.Status NOT IN ('1', '4')
                 INNER JOIN tbl_vulnerability AS v
                    ON i.VulId = v.VulId
                 GROUP BY
                    YEAR(i.OpenDt)
                  , MONTH(i.OpenDt)
                  , v.VulId
                  , v.VulName
                ) c
             )
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        CTE c
    WHERE
        c.Totals IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3
                        Totals
                     FROM
                        CTE
                     ORDER BY
                        Totals DESC);
```

**Edited**: Moved the order by to fix the query.

Comment: Could you give a sample of the output you actually expect so I can revise my query.
Actually I've just spoted my mistake. I placed the Order by outside the subquery. How dump...

Comment: It should work now that I moved the Order By statement where it belongs.
Sorry for that.

Comment: from your cte you are selecting top 3 Totals OrderBy Totals but if the Totals of more than one Vulname are same then Your Query is resulting in more than 3 types of Vulname, i want only top 3 types of VulName

Comment: then my query isn't answering your question.
I try to share another answer then

Answer (score 0):

Based on new information on the requirement I suggest the following query:

```
WITH    CTE
          AS (
                 SELECT
                    YEAR(i.OpenDt) AS Years
                  , MONTH(i.OpenDt) AS Months
                  , v.VulId
                  , v.VulName
                  , COUNT(v.VulId) AS Vulcount
                  , SUM(COUNT(v.VulId)) OVER (PARTITION BY VulId) AS Totals
                 FROM
                    tbl_apptestdetails AS atd
                 INNER JOIN tbl_applicationlist AS al
                    ON atd.appid = al.appid
                 INNER JOIN tbl_bu AS bu
                    ON bu.buid = al.buid
                 INNER JOIN tbl_Issues AS i
                    ON atd.testdetailid = i.testdetailid
                       AND i.Status NOT IN ('1', '4')
                 INNER JOIN tbl_vulnerability AS v
                    ON i.VulId = v.VulId
                 GROUP BY
                    YEAR(i.OpenDt)
                  , MONTH(i.OpenDt)
                  , v.VulId
                  , v.VulName
             ) ,
        cte2
          AS (
              SELECT
                c.Years
              , c.Months
              , c.Vulcount
              , c.VulName
              , c.Totals
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.VulId ORDER BY C.Totals DESC) AS RowNum
              FROM
                CTE c
             )
    SELECT
        c.Years
      , c.Months
      , c.VulName
      , c.Vulcount
      , c.Totals
    FROM
        cte2 c
    WHERE
        c.RowNum <=3
    ORDER BY
        c.Totals;
```

Comment: In first cte there would be Partition by v.VulId ,  Its giving wrong output, query is giving many vulnarabilities

Comment: It will give you the total number of occurrence for each vulId. the first cte is the exact equivalent of the 1st cte in my previous answer. just simplified.
but as I don't have the dataset nor the expected result I can check it.

Comment: So first Cte gives the total number of occurrence for each vulid, Now Order them in Totals Desc, After that select only Top 3 distinct Vulid, but order by should remain on Totals

Comment: I've added the Order By statement.

Comment: No Kirlen this query is not helping

Comment: one way to get right result is to add a column  which contains '1' from rownumber 23 to 29 , '2' from rownumber 30 to 38 ,'3' from rownumber 39 to 42 and so on  and then pic up all those records whose new column value is equal to 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: I think I now understand what you are looking for. you want only 3 records in total. for each of the 3 most frequent vulId you want only 1 records. do you want a random one or the month with higher occurence or the latest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125997/discussion-between-kilren-and-ashu).